# How do I enable CTRL right/right arrow key to move word wise in shell?

Tags: shell, key-binding

I tried all the tips mentioned in this article:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029118/bash-ctrl-to-move-cursor-between-words-strings

But non work for me...

Is there a way to work it out ?

Comment: Using which shell and which terminal?

Comment: @grawity,I'm connecting to linux from windows by ssh.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all. Which shell (bash, sh, zsh, csh, ...) and which terminal (PuTTY, Mintty, Xterm, Konsole, Cygwin SSH, SecureCRT, ...)?

Comment: @grawity, I'm using xshell, bash.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple - Xshell *does not send anything* when you press Ctrl+arrows. And you can't configure it to send proper escape sequences, either.

It may be possible to configure Ctrl-Left and Ctrl-Right via "Keyboard Shortcuts" to send some very unlikely to type sequence, but it will cause much headache in the future.

The only proper solution is to choose a different client, such as PuTTY or SecureCRT.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with the keyboard?